# pick the functions which generate error (pointers in C)

Tags: c, function, pointers

So I have 3 functions and I need to tell which function can generate error (about working with pointers) if I call these function in a program. The functions are:

```
int* f1(void) {
  int *p=0;
  int x=10;
  p = &x;
  return p;
}
```

```
int* f2(void) {
  int *px=0;
  *px=10;
  return px;
}
```

```
int* f3(void) 
{
    int* px = 0;
    px = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if ( px == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    *px=10;
    return px;
}
```

I am pretty sure that f2 is wrong. I need to pick one of these variants:

```
1. f1 & f3
2. none of them
3. f1 & f2
4. all of them
```

I analyzed f1 and f3 and it seems to me that there is nothing wrong with them. Am I miss something ?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I'm preparing for a test

Comment: We're not here to answer your exam or practice test questions. This site is for questions about problems you're having with actual code.

Comment: `f3`, other than the casting of `malloc`'s result, seems fine.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions You could for example explain in detail your thinking and your analysis. Then we can much more helpfully answer to your benefit by checking your logic, pointing out the mistakes and helping you to understand.

Comment: This is how I analyzed f2 function: px pointer points to null so I can't use the * operator to acces the value of which px points because there's no value, it's null.

Comment: For f1, I have a pointer which points to null and a variable. Then, pointer gets the adress of x and also it is pointing to x. My opinion is that nothing is wrong here. The function returns the adress of x.

Comment: For f3, I have a pointer which points to null then I allocate a block of memory so now the pointers points to the adress of the block which I allocated. I make the check such that the pointer to not point to null. Here, I'm a littble bit unsure, I try to store the 10 value to the block I allocated using the pointer.

Comment: You are correct about `f2`. `f3` seems fine to me. Talking about `f1` it will not cause a crash like `f2` but it is wrong as well. Why? Hint: what value will be assigned to the returned pointer? Will be safe using it outside the function?

Comment: The returned pointer points to x value so *p will be 10, right ? I tend to think that f1 is wrong because if I use that pointer outside the function I will have no memory allocated, am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

- In the first function,

```cpp
int* f1(void) {
  int *p=0;   // This defines an integer pointer with the value of 0x00.
  int x=10;   // This defines an integer variable storing the value 10 by default.
  p = &x;     // This assigns p with the address of the stack allocated memory block of x.
  return p;   // This returns the pointer stored in p.
}
```

The issue with this function is that since `int x = 10;` is allocated in the stack, as soon as the function goes out of scope, the pointer gets deallocated. But since your not doing anything like dereferencing it the pointer before assigning an address to it or assigning a value the pointer which points to a null space, the function itself doesn't produce an error. But if your going to use the pointer returned by the function, then a stack corruption could occur.

- In the second function,

```cpp
int* f2(void) {
  int *px=0;    // This defines an integer pointer with the value of 0x00.
  *px=10;       // This assigns the value 10 to the memory block pointed by the pointer.
  return px;    // This returns the pointer.
}
```

In the above function, your assigning a value to a memory that doesn't exist in the memory. This will definitely trigger a write access violation. And the return of the function is always 0x00.

- In the third function,

```cpp
int* f3(void) 
{
   int* px = 0;                       // This defines an integer pointer with the value of 0x00.
   px = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));    // This allocates memory in heap which might or might not be a successful allocation and you assign it to px.
   if ( px == 0) {                    // This checks if the allocation was successful. 
       fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   
   *px=10;                            // This sets the value 10 to the memory block pointed by px.
   return px;                         // This returns the pointer stored in px.
}
```

This function is correct as in the function scope and for the value returned by the function. The only warning is that you must deallocate the allocated memory block.

This means that out of these 3 functions, the 3rd function is the most correct one.